# Spring - Inject Dependency based on properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Does Spring Boot have a way to inject a dependency with the class name and constructor properties provided in the config file?

For example, I have two version of a common interface, `IFileStore`, `FileStoreA` and `FileStoreB`. I want to be able to define which of these I should use in the `application.yml` file.

I know I can do something like this:

```
@Value("${fileStore.class}")
private String fileStoreClassName;

@Bean
public IFileStore fileStore() {
    switch(fileStoreClassName) {
        case "FileStoreA":
            return new FileStoreA();
        case "FileStoreB":
            return new FileStoreB();
    }
}
```

This however feels really hacky. I'd also have to manually extract and supply any required parameters to them.

My ideal would be that it's able to determine which to use based on the class name, and also provide any parameters the specific one needs, so if I add a third `FileStore`, it'd auto-magically work and I'd just have to use that for the class name instead.

Comment: When you say 'it's able to determine which to use based on the class name'.  What is 'it'?  Are you auto wiring these objects?  How are you using the FileStore?

Comment: Yeah. Basically I'd `@Autowired IFileStore fileStore` in the class that actually needs to use it directly, regardless of the underlying implementation. The example `FileStore` just has three functions: `get()`, `save()` and `has()` for basic "file" access (may not always be an actual file on the file system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really only need a single bean, then create a conditional configuration

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "fileStore.class", havingValue="FileStoreA")
public class FileStoreAConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IFileStore fileStore() {
        return new FileStoreA(...);
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "fileStore.class", havingValue="FileStoreB")
public class FileStoreBConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IFileStore fileStore() {
        return new FileStoreB(...);
    }
}
```

It's actually easier than that, as the annotation can be used on a method instead, rather than having separate configuration classes.

See the [ConditionalOnProperty Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Profiles (`@Profile` annotation) in order to configure the same @Bean but with different implementations.

For example, you can make a production configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // ...

}
```

So, for your example, you can configure how many profiles you require and then you can specify the property in any of the usual ways, for example, you could include it in your `application.properties`.

For further details, you can read [Spring Boot features - Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: Is there a way to have this trickle down, kind of how "application.yml" trickles down to "application-prod.yml"? We have quite a few environments, but only 2 different profiles. Having a profile for each would be a bunch of work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for [XML-based configuration](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/)?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="fileStore" class="com.example.FileStoreA">
       <property name="parameter1" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```